# How to specify the ssh key on the remote host?

Tags: linux, ssh, key-authentication

I am not an admin and therefore I do not have access rights to the remote server.
I accidentally moved all the files and folders of the remote host to a new folder, so the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is not in the right place.

I wanted to know if it is possible to specify the path to this file in the ssh command by the client?
(We do `-i` to specify the location of the key on the client side, but is it possible to do the same thing on the server side?

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/id.rsa user_name@serveur.com -? <path_to_authorized_keys_on_serveur>`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You asked if there was any way "*to specify the path to this file [on the server] in the ssh command by the client"*.

No this is not possible.

Either you need to log in with password authentication or ask the systems administrators to move the files and directories back again.